# In R, generate weighted sample with probability applied to multiple variables

Tags: r

I have a matrix with several variables and a probability of occurrence for all the variables. I want to generate the weighted sample not for each vector independently but for all the variables (since there is correlation among them).

```
V1  V2  V3  prob
30  40  40  0.4
0   5   5   0.2
15  20  30  0.4
```

I want to generate a matrix sample with V1, V2 and V3 that takes into account the simultaneous occurrence of certain values.

Comment: Interesting question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would actually need exactly the equivalent of this function `sample(x, size = 1000, prob = prob)` but with the possibility to put a matrix for x (and not just a vector)

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of the first row? That P(V1 = 30, V2 = 40, V3 = 40) = 0.4? So that (V1,V2,V3) can take only three different values?

Comment: `inx <- sample(nrow(x), 1000, prob = prob)`. Then subset `x[inx, ]`.

Comment: Yes, in this case, I want to stick to the three possible values I have in my data set. So that I have a probability of 0.4 that the three variables reach these certain values and a probability of 0.2 that they are very low, for instance. @RuiBarradas I don't see how `sample(3,1000,prob=prob)` would work?
@PoGibas I would need a matrix with three columns and 1000 rows. 40% of the rows would give my first row, 20% the second row, 40% the third one.

Comment: Then maybe simple `x[rep(1:nrow(x), x$prob * 1e3), ]` would work. If you need exact fraction then you don't need to sample.

Comment: (I forgot argument `replace = TRUE`). `sample(3, ...)` will sample the vector `1:3`. This can be used to subset the matrix. Suppose the sample is `inx <- c(2, 2, 1, 3)`. `x[inx, ]` is the matrix with two rows 2 of the original, then one row 1, then one row 3.

Comment: But if I aggregate all the matrix in one vector, how can I associate the probability for each observation of the three variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual usage of `sample` is to simulate values of a single random variable. When dealing, as in your case, with a random vector (X,Y,Z) of *dependent* discrete random variables, it becomes necessary to know their joint distribution. It happens that in your case it's very simple, as they are "perfectly" dependent. Following @Rui Barradas idea, we can use

```
df[sample(nrow(df), n, replace = TRUE, prob = df$prob), -ncol(df)]
```

to generate `n` vectors. By the law of large numbers, as `n` increases, you will get closer and closer to the desired 40%, 20%, and 40%. If you need those precise percentages also with few draws, then your question is not about generating.

Comment: @Anais, does that answer your question?